# How to make 'resources' in routes to use controller outside namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have contact model that are polymorhic. I have one controller  that are outside of :admin namespace that handle  CRUD for different types. How to make this :contacts resources to point to controller that are outside of :admin namespace?

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :schools do
    resources :campuses, :controller => 'schools/campuses' do
      resources :contacts # problem controller
    end
  end
end
```

Best regards,
Georgi Tapalilov

Comment: Can you specify the error message that you are getting for this routing?

Comment: rspec raise this exception:  ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Gaku::Admin::ContactsController):

Comment: Its difficult to say what you are trying to achieve but may be instead of namespace, you just need nested resources. If so, replace `namespace :admin` with `resources :admin`

Comment: i don`t need admin resoureces. i just need to use controller that are not namespaced under :admin for contacts

Comment: then why can't you use `resources :contacts` outside of namespace in your routes?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
resources :campuses

namespace :admin do
  resources :schools do
    resources :campuses, :controller => 'schools/campuses' do
      resources :contacts
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: my idea is to use controller for contacts that are not nested under /admin/ folder